# Jquery Mobile Navbar button image Fit

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I am working on query mobile in intel xdm . Used query1.4.1.js and trying to modify navbar (custom navbar). I am having problem in setting background of each button of navbar. If i set images in background of nag bar it is not proportionate to the button like **`<li style="background:url(someImage.png)"><a href=""></a></li>`** it gets out of the button but if i set image with image tag like  **`<li><a href=""><img src=""/></a></li>`** it is setting image in centre of the button like red button in this link [Navbar Image Background](http://jsfiddle.net/vTBGa/30/) if i set its width and height to 100% image will be placed in centre and will gives padding/spaces on top left bottom and right. I want to exact set the background of each button in nav bar. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your jsfiddle images did not load for me.

Comment: @Joseph please see my updated fiddle

Comment: I am still a little confused... Are you talking about trying to remove the padding around the images that is created by jQuery Mobile? like this http://jsfiddle.net/vTBGa/32/ (I removed the red background from showing.)

Comment: @Joseph exactly that i was looking for. Actually that padding i want to remove. And thanks your code solved my problem.